# Select query to find the constraint which has PK/FK in one table to list all the related tables in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2017

Could you help to get the select query to list all the related tables to the PK/FK of another table)

I have 3 tables, `Table1` contains `cust_ID` (PK) and other 2 tables (`table2` and `table3`) have a FK to `Table1`.

Need to use constraints for filter all the related tables and list in the output specifically list the Reference Table and Reference column and Reference Key from table2 and table3 - may be in production to list all the relatable tables and columns (in millions)

Unable to fetch the 2 columns Reference Table and Reference column and Reference Key(complete list).

Could you help to list all the foreign key tables and columns based on the other primary key from another table

The primary key (in `table1`) should list the foreign keys (in `Table2` and `Table3`) with their table and column name.

Table1

| cust_ID | cust_Name |
| --- | --- |
| 10001 | John |
| 10002 | Peter |
| 10003 | Steve |
| 10004 | Mike |
| 10005 | Rob |

Table2

| cust_ID_bk | cust_Pay |
| --- | --- |
| 10001 | 10 |
| 10002 | 20 |

Table3

| cust_ID_sk | cust_Phone# |
| --- | --- |
| 10001 | 1234567890 |
| 10002 | 2023456789 |
| 10003 | 5678904345 |

Expected Output

| CONSTRAINT_Name | CONSTRAINT_Type | TABLE_NAME | COLUMN NAME | Reference Table | Reference Column | Reference Key |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| SYS_12345 | Primary Key | Table1 | cust_ID | Table2 | cust_ID_bk | Foreign Key |
| SYS_12345 | Primary Key | Table1 | cust_ID | Table3 | cust_ID_sk | Foreign Key |

I tried using below query but I am unable to fetch the Reference Table and Reference column and Reference Key and Reference Key

```
select 
    a.CONSTRAINT_NAME, a.CONSTRAINT_TYPE, a.TABLE_NAME,
    b.COLUMN_NAME, b.Reference Table, b.Reference Column, b.Reference Key
from 
    INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLE_CONSTRAINTS a, 
    INFORMATION_SCHEMA.KEY_COLUMN_USAGE b
where 
    a.CONSTRAINT_NAME = b.CONSTRAINT_NAME
    and a.table_name = 'Table1'
```

Comment: [Bad habits to kick : using old-style JOINs](https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/08/bad-habits-to-kick-using-old-style-joins) - that old-style *comma-separated list of tables* style was replaced with the *proper* ANSI `JOIN` syntax in the ANSI-**92** SQL Standard (more than **30 years!!** ago) and its use is discouraged+

Comment: [Bad habits to kick : using table aliases like (a, b, c) or (t1, t2, t3)](https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/08/bad-habits-to-kick-using-table-aliases-like-a-b-c-or-t1-t2-t3)

Answer (score 0):

```
create table Table1(cust_ID int,
                    cust_Name varchar(50),
                    CONSTRAINT [SYS_12345] Primary key  (cust_id )
                   );

create table Table2(cust_ID_bk int, 
                    cust_Pay varchar(50),
                    Foreign key (cust_ID_bk) references Table1(Cust_ID)
                  );

create table Table3(cust_ID_sk int, 
                   cust_Phone# varchar(50),
                   Foreign key (cust_ID_sk) references Table1(Cust_ID)
                 );
```

Query:

```
select 
    a.CONSTRAINT_NAME, a.CONSTRAINT_TYPE, a.TABLE_NAME,
    b.COLUMN_NAME, object_name(fkc.parent_object_id) Reference_Table,
    col.name Reference_Column ,'Foreign Key' as ReferenceKey
from 
    INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLE_CONSTRAINTS a 
inner join 
    INFORMATION_SCHEMA.KEY_COLUMN_USAGE b on a.CONSTRAINT_NAME = b.CONSTRAINT_NAME
left join 
    sys.foreign_key_columns fkc on a.TABLE_NAME =  object_name(fkc.referenced_object_id) 
left join
    sys.columns AS col ON fkc.parent_object_id = col.object_id 
                       AND fkc.parent_column_id = col.column_id
where  
    a.table_name = 'Table1' and a.CONSTRAINT_TYPE='PRIMARY KEY'
```

OUtput:

| CONSTRAINT_NAME | CONSTRAINT_TYPE | TABLE_NAME | COLUMN_NAME | Reference_Table | Reference_Column | ReferenceKey |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| SYS_12345 | PRIMARY KEY | Table1 | cust_ID | Table2 | cust_ID_bk | Foreign Key |
| SYS_12345 | PRIMARY KEY | Table1 | cust_ID | Table3 | cust_ID_sk | Foreign Key |

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/tQ38OoE3)

Comment: I see 3 rows (in current staging table), 1st row does have Contrainst_Type as "Primary Key" and the Reference Table and Reference Column are NULL

Comment: Based upon the primary key (in this case, cust_ID), it should retrieve all the foreign keys

Comment: I have edited Reference Key in the expected output

Comment: @AntonyPrincePeter now I think I understood your problem. I have modified my answer to select the primary key of a table and all the reference tables with columns against it.